# Java compiler error: "cannot find symbol constructor .."?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, compiler-errors

i'm writing code for employee, manager, hourly worker for a class assignment but i've hit a problem that i can't figure out, the following is my code for employee followed by hourly worker.  the problem is hourly worker won't compile, it's giving a "cannot find symbol constructor employee" error when i try to compile (employee class compiiles without issue.  any suggestions please?  i think i've been staring at it for so long i can no longer see the problem!  thanks.  pieter.

**EMPLOYEE CLASS -**

```
public class Employee
{
   public String firstName;
   public String lastName;
   public double hourlyRate;
   final static double NORMAL_WORKWEEK = 37.5;

   public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, double hourlyRate)
   {
       setFirstName(firstName);
       setLastName(lastName);
       setHourlyRate(hourlyRate);
    }
    //Accessor and Mutator Methods for the employee's first name.
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        firstName = firstName;
    }
   //Accessor and Mutator Methods for the employee's last name.
     public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        lastName = lastName;
    }
    //Access and Mutator Methods for the employee's hourly rate.
    public double getHourlyRate()
    {
        return hourlyRate;
    }
    public void setHourlyRate(double hourlyRate)
    {
    //If the user input is valid, update the employee's hour rate with the newly input value.

    if(hourlyRate > 0)
    {
      hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
        }
      //Otherwise prevent an hour rate greater than zero being overwritten 
        else if(hourlyRate <=0)
        {

   if(hourlyRate <= 0)
   {           
            hourlyRate = 0;
            }

  decorateConsole();

  //Alert the user to their mistake.
  System.out.println("Error ! ! ! - An attempt to set the employee " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "'s hourly rate to zero was detected.\n");

  decorateConsole();

  }


 }

 public void printState()
 {

  decorateConsole();

  System.out.println("[FIRST NAME] = " + firstName + " [LAST NAME] = " + lastName + " [HOURLY RATE] = " + hourlyRate + "\n");

  decorateConsole();

 }

 public void decorateConsole()
 {

  System.out.println("+-< EMPLOYEE INFO >-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");

 }
```

**HOURLY WORKER CLASS -**

```
public class HourlyWorker extends Employee
{
   private double wage;
   private double hours;

   public HourlyWorker(String firstName, String lastName, double hourlyWage, double hoursWorked)
   {
       super(firstName, lastName);
       this.wage = wage;
       this.hours = hours;
    }

    public void setWage (double hourlyWage)
    {
       this.wage = wage;
    }
    public void getWage()
    {
        return wage;
    }
    public void setHours (double hours)
    {
        this.hours = hours;
    }
    public double getHours()
    {
        return hours;
    }




}
```

Comment: I suggest you to paste the error code next time, It's easier to spot the error that way.

Comment: Your setters are broken. `firstName = firstName` - that assign value of `firstName` (local variable) to the local variable `firstName` (ie. it overrides itself). You should write `this.firstName = firstName`.

Answer (score 9):

You don't have a `Employee` constructor with two parameters:

```
super(firstName, lastName);
```

Try using:

```
super(firstName, lastName, 0.0);
```

**EDIT** as per tony request, here's a more detailed explanation.

With `super(firstName, lastName);` you're invoking ( trying to invoke ) a constructor in the class `Employee` which has two string parameters.

Reviewing the `Employee` class definition, we see you don't have such constructor, but you have one with three parameters:

```
public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, double hourlyRate)
```

So, the solution is to invoke that constructor instead. Since you don't have a default value for `hourlyRate`  we can use 0.0 which is a double.

Other alternative would be to create a two parameter constructor in the `Employee` class

```
public Employee(String firstName, String lastName )
```

Comment: thanks oscar, by adding the 0.0 (and changing public void getWage to public double getWage) it compliles but i don't understand why, could you explain how that 0.0 resolved it, or at least appears to have resolved it please?

Comment: @tony: Surre, I have updated the answer, let me know if is clear enough

Comment: thanks oscar, that's very helpful - i especially appreciate the rapid response!  tony

Answer (score 4):

In the HourlyWorker constructor you tried to call the Employee constructor like this:

```
super(firstName, lastName);
```

but the Employee class doesn't have a constructor with two parameters. You need to pass a third parameter (hourly rate) like this:

```
super(firstName, lastName, 42);
```

Comment: i see thanks, oscarryz mentioned something similar above and that explains it, thanks for your assistance snakile

Answer (score 2):

In `HourlyWorker` you call

```
super(firstName, lastName);
```

but the `Employee` constructor is

```
Employee(String, String, double)
```

The signatures don't match.

EDIT: Incidentally, why does the HourlyWorker have a private `wage` member? How is it different (conceptually) to `Employee.hourlyRate`?

Comment: thanks cameron, the duplication of private wage and hourly rate is my error, will fix that up too!  cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In your HourlyWorker class you are calling the constructor of Employee {super(firstname, lastname)} with two arguments but in Employee class you do not have any constructors that take two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a super constructor that takes only two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`HourlyWorker`'s constructor tries to call `super(firstName, lastName)`, but there's no such constructor declared in the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

In your HourlyWorker class, you have the following line of code:

```
super(firstName, lastName);
```

But, there is no matching constructor in your employee class.  Basically, the compiler is looking in your employee class for something like...

```
public Employee(String firstName, String lastName)
{
   ...
}
```

Define a new constructor, or call the constructor you've defined with the parameters you're missing.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick feedback, much appreciated!  I think it's ok now, it's compiling at least (as per oscar and snakile's input above).

Answer (score 1):

You are calling HourlyEmployee's base class constructor (which is Employee's ctor) with 2 arguments instead of the 3 it wants.

Change the line in HourlyEmployee ctor from:

```
super(firstName, lastName);
```

to

```
super(firstName, lastName, hourlyWage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are still wanting to have a constructor like

`public Employee(String firstName, String lastName)
{
   ...
}`

and you know the default value from your `double hourlyRate`, you can try to write a new constructor like the next one:

`public Employee(String firstName, String lastName)
{

```
     Employee(firstName, lastName, 0.0);
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

There's something fishy going on around the `else if` here. It's repeated with another if and some curly braces missing. Indent your code properly and make sure the open curlys matches the closing ones.

```
   if(hourlyRate > 0)
    {
      hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
        }
      //Otherwise prevent an hour rate greater than zero being overwritten 
        else if(hourlyRate <=0)
        {

   if(hourlyRate <= 0)
   {           
            hourlyRate = 0;
            }

  decorateConsole();
```

Also, these kind of lines won't work as intended (you have three of them):

```
   firstName = firstName;
```

It must be:

```
   this.firstName = firstName;
```

Like you have in your second class.